# fundamental solution of Pell’s equation under special conditions

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, pell-type-equations

I make the following conjecture from [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4443849/a-pattern-that-leads-to-regular-continued-fractions-of-quadratic-irrationals/4443887#4443887).

---

**conjecture**

Suppose $N$ could be expressed as

$$
N= p^2\pm q,\ \ \ \ (p,q \in \mathbb{N},\ 1 \lt q \lt p,\ q\mid 2p)
$$

In this case, the fundamental solution of $x^2-Ny^2=1$ is obtained by the following expression. (double sign in same order)

$$
x_0=\frac{2p^2}{q} \pm 1,\ \ y_0=\frac{2p}{q}
$$

---

$(x_0,y_0)$ is one of the solutions of $x^2-Ny^2=1$ because it can be calculated as follows.

\begin{eqnarray*}
x_0^2-Ny_0^2&=& \left(\frac{2p^2}{q} \pm 1\right)^2-(p^2\pm q)\cdot \left(\frac{2p}{q}\right)^2\\
&=& \frac{4p^4}{q^2} \pm \frac{4p^2}{q} +1 -\frac{4p^4}{q^2} \mp\frac{4p^2}{q}\\
&=& 1
\end{eqnarray*}

But, **I don't know how to prove that it is the fundamental solution.**

---

**concrete example**

Let $N$ be $75$.

The expression using the square number of the nearest neighbors is

$$
75 = 9^2-6
$$

$p=9,\ q=6$ satisfy $1 \lt q \lt p$ and $\ q\mid 2p$.

Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray*}
x_0&=&\frac{2p^2}{q} - 1,\ \ \ \ y_0&=&\frac{2p}{q} \\
&=& \frac{2\cdot 9^2}{6} -1    &=& \frac{2\cdot 9}{6} \\
&=& 26 &=& 3
\end{eqnarray*}

$(x_0, y_0) = (26, 3)$ is the fundamental solution of $x^2-75y^2=1$.

Comment: I programmed it, succeeds for your $p^2 \pm q < 10000.$ The primes you can express are some $p^2 + 2$   and some $p^2 - 2.$  The CF's are known, so Pell fundamental is known, with $\delta = \pm 1,$   then $n = p^2 + 2 \delta,$   and $p \geq 3,$  fundamental is $  (p^2 + \delta)^2 - n p^2 =1 $  You should find Pell fundamental for a few primes that don't fit your description, such as $19$ and $13$

Comment: google Richaud-Degert, parametrized fundamental units